# Is there a Bug in Pandas Dataframe Assignment?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame named df, and in this dataframe, I have a column named 'to_be_pred' that is a boolean, which takes True or False. When I work on this dataframe, I create a dataframe called df_temp and take the rows that have a True value in the `to_be_pred` column to this dataframe. After doing some operations on the df_temp dataframe, I assign the values back to the main dataframe, which is df. However, I discovered that:

```py
df_temp = df[df['to_be_pred']].copy()
... do some stuff with df_temp ...
df.loc[df['to_be_pred'], ['A', 'B', 'to_be_pred', 'C']] = df_temp[['A', 'B', 'to_be_pred', 'C']]
```

When I run this code above, the df dataframe has the values of df_temp for 'A', 'B', and `to_be_pred` correctly. However, 'C' values can't be assigned to df.

After trying many things, the issue was resolved with this code:

```py
df.loc[df['to_be_pred'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'to_be_pred']] = df_temp[['A', 'B', 'C', 'to_be_pred']]
```

Is this a bug, or is there something that I don't know?

pd.**version**: '2.0.3'

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the two inputs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.